# Does Unity interface relate to Unity3D?

Tags: unity

They share the same name, if they don't relate to each other than do they have copyright conflicts between each other?

Comment: One can now copyright words?

Comment: binary numbers can be copyrighted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Unity, the Ubuntu user interface, is not related to Unity3D, the game engine.

Comment: But they share the same name, if they're not related dont they have copyright problems?

Comment: No. Copyright law has nothing to do with naming, generally. It would be trademark law, and "unity" really is too common a name. If you want exact details, ask a lawyer. Ask Ubuntu is not the place to ask for legal advice.